# Got problem with setup.py when install ssl

Tags: python

I tried to install ssl package for my computer (Pop_OS 21.10) with the command `python3 -m pip install ssl`. Then pip returned this mess:

```
Processing ./ssl-1.16.tar.gz
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-765tgjcs/setup.py", line 33
          print 'looking for', f
                ^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('looking for', f)?
      Error in sys.excepthook:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
          from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
          from apport.report import Report
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
          from urllib.request import urlopen
        File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
          import http.client
        File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1391, in <module>
          import ssl
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-765tgjcs/ssl/__init__.py", line 140
          except SSLError, x:
                         ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      
      Original exception was:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-req-build-765tgjcs/setup.py", line 33
          print 'looking for', f
                ^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('looking for', f)?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have checked pip version (22.0.4) and setuptools (62.1.0), it seem normal.
What is the problem in here? How can I solve it?

Comment: ssl is part of the standard library. You shouldn't need to install it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html Have you tried `import ssl` in python3? You're currently trying to install a python2 backport, which is why you are getting an error.

Comment: Thank you! Helped me a lot. I don’t understand why it’s not giving a smarter error message like telling me I want to install something that is for python2.